# What is the wind speed metric in here observation api?

Tags: here-api

I have a question regarding wind speed metric in Here Weather Observation API. 
Following is the link and example.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/weather/topics/example-weather-observation.html

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is, whether wind speed in the example link "windSpeed":"5.56" is the 5.56 value measured mph or km/h.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for the definition of WindSpeed , if yes then here it is :

> Wind speed in km/h or mph. If the element is in the response and it
>   contains a value, there is a Double in the String.

```
            <windSpeed>1.85</windSpeed>
```

> If the element is
>   in the response and it does not contain a value, there is an asterisk
>   (*) in the String.

```
<windSpeed>*</windSpeed>
```

for more detail about metric and these parameters you can go through the link :

https://developer.here.com/documentation/weather/topics/resource-report.html#resource-report__param-product

Hope this help !

Comment: What I understood from the documentation is the metric parameter should be set to false if the response of the wind speed needs to be in miles

Comment: @smamaj Yes, You can set metric as False in order to get wind speed in imperial units (feet, inch, Fahrenheit, miles).